# Accommodation requirements for a UK spouse visa

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I have a question regarding the accommodation requirement of a UK spouse visa. My wife is a British citizen but the place she is staying in is under receivership and she has been given a 2-month notice to leave the premises. She went ahead and secured another place, a one-bedroom apartment plus a seating room, bathroom, toilet and a kitchen.

Now I'm worried because the place is new, which means there are no utility bills or council tax bill. Will it be OK if I procede with the visa and use just the tenancy agreement and a letter from the landlord saying that I'm permitted to stay in that property?

Many thanks.